# Exactness in category theory

Tags: category-theory, homology-cohomology, exact-sequence, abelian-categories

In MacLane's 'Category Theory for the working mathematician' there is a definition of exactness (page 200):

'A composable pair of arrows $f: a\rightarrow b$ and $g: b\rightarrow c$ is exact at b if im $f$ $\equiv$ ker $g$ (as subobjects of $b$).'

Here, im $f$ is defined to be ker (coker $f$). In the next paragraph he states that im $f$ $\leq$ ker $g$ if and only if $gf = 0$, and im $f$ $\geq$ ker $g$ if and only if every $k$ with $gk = 0$ factors as $k = m k'$, where $m$ is such that $f = me$ for $m$ monic, $e$ epic.

I cannot figure out why those equivalences hold. Can someone explain how one can prove them?

Note: We are working in an abelian category.

Comment: Are you working on a general abelian category?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime I have found a proof for both equivalences, but tiks does not seem to work here, so I will just show you a scan of my handwritten notes.

[answer.pdf](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UyJghLdJs_kGiL4ND_XEgz-FQ6v_9KHK)

Comment: There is no way to use Tikz, but you can still draw diagrams, see [this Meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16888/245577) (it's quite limited compared to Tikz, though).

Comment: This is good to know, thank you! But I still think with this tool it would take very long to draw all diagrams I used, so I think I will leave it as it is.